# Reading specific columns using TextFieldparser class in c#?

Tags: c#

So,I was using textfieldparser to read a csv file and get the result from it. But the way the data is being printed is a bit different. I get the data row by row. What I am aiming at is to pass the name of a column or column index and get the data from that column and store in a container so that I can create a table or something that I can append to a pdf file for report generation. This is what I tried so far.

```
public void ReadCSV()
    {
        using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser("t.csv"))
        {
            parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
            parser.SetDelimiters(",");
            while (!parser.EndOfData)
            {
                //Processing row
                string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
                foreach (string field in fields)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(field);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

//I would like to get the data from column index 4, 7,13, 17,21. So, how do I get it work in such a way that I can query random column indexes.

Comment: fields is an array, array values can be read by their index. `fields[4]` would work.

Comment: `int[] indices = new int[] { 4, 7, 13, 17, 21 }; IEnumerable<string> columns = parser.ReadFields().Select((field, index) => new { field = field, index = index }).Where(fi => indicex.Contains(fi.index)).Select(fi => fi.field);`

Comment: @rene:- Thanks very much

Comment: @m.rogalski:- Thanks a lot.